# How do I change the return type of a <select> <option> field?

Tags: html, angularjs

So I got this `<select>` field with different `<option>`s

Now I wanna use this form to call a method and give it the chosen `input`s and `option`s as parameters.

```
<tr>
      <th>Father: </th>
      <th><select #father id="father">
        <option *ngFor="let fatherHorse of horses" [value]="fatherHorse"
                [selected]="horse.father == fatherHorse">{{fatherHorse.name}}</option>
      </select></th>
</tr>
```

`horses` is a list with Horse elements. However, when trying to call my Method which requires a `Horse` as input with `fatherHorse` as parameter, the compiler tells me that my `fatherHorse` is of type `String`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment, but did you try use the
`[ngValue]="faterHorse"` instead of `[value]="fatherHorse"` ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't seem to work.
"ngValue is not provided by any applicable directives nor by option element"